# Is there any reason why jQuery Sortable would work in IE/Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a fairly straightforward list of horizontally floated items, like this:

```
<div class="my-widget-container">
    <div class="my-widget-column">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Both the container and each column have a fixed width, set using jQuery's `.width()`.  The container is `position: relative` and the column is `float: left` and `overflow: hidden`.  Not sure if any other styles/properties are relevant.

When I apply a jQuery-UI sortable to this, the result is exactly what I'd expect in Chome 8 and IE 8; the columns can be dragged around to change their order.  But in Firefox 3.6 I can click an item and drag to create a new sort-helper, yet the actual sort never happens; the real item's position in the DOM never changes.

I dug around a little in Sortable, and added a debug print to `_intersectsWithPointer`.  Whenever the drag helper moves, Sortable runs through its list of elements and uses this method to determine whether the drag helper has passed over one.  What I saw was that `item.left` had the same value for all my columns, which is obviously not correct, and probably the source of the problem.  It looks like all columns had a `left` position corresponding to that of the first column.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.3 and jQuery UI Sortable 1.8.  Those aren't the very latest versions, but they're pretty recent, and I don't see anything in the Sortable release notes that indicates any such problem has been fixed.

Does anyone know what might be happening here, or have any ideas for further debugging?

Comment: Do you have the Firebug plug-in for Firefox? I have found that to be invaluable when debugging JavaScript issues. Maybe it can give you some additional feedback. In addition, if you could post the bits of code you discuss (the HTML, the CSS, and the JavaScript/jQuery), that would be helpful.

Comment: Just as an update - I tried to emulate what you described above, and everything works fine for me (in all browsers). So, if you can post more code, I may be able to help. I'll wait until I hear back from you.